# How can I get image from Firebase Storage and display them in Angular 2 ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-storage, monaca

I'm trying to display image in *ngFor which I downloaded from Firebase Storage.

I succeeded fetching image data from storage, but I don't know how to set image data in ngFor statement.

Let me show you my code here.

```
<ons-list-item class="list__item list__item--chevron" tappable *ngFor="let request of requests | async" (click)="pushToDetail(request)">
    <ons-row>
      <ons-col width="20%"><img [src]="userProfileImg"></ons-col>
      <ons-col style="padding-left:20px;">
        <p class="name"><i class="fa fa-venus fa-fw" aria hidden="true"></i>{{request.nickName}}</p>
      </ons-col>
    </ons-row>
</ons-list-item>
```

And this is the code to download image. I wrote this one in foreach when I subscribed FirebaseListObservable data.

```
getProfileImageUrl(userId: string) {
    const userStorageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('images/users/' + userId + "_users.jpg");
    userStorageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
      this.userProfileImg = url
    });
  }
```

Then I'd like you to teach me how to literate images from Firebase Storage. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the image unique to each item in the array you are iterating? From the above code it seems that you are showing the same image for all rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the image is unique to each array element:

```
<ons-list-item class="list__item list__item--chevron" tappable *ngFor="let request of requests | async" (click)="pushToDetail(request)">
    <ons-row>
      <ons-col width="20%"><img [src]="userProfileImg"></ons-col>
      <ons-col style="padding-left:20px;">
        <p class="name"><i class="fa fa-venus fa-fw" aria hidden="true"></i>{{request.nickName}}</p>
      </ons-col>
    </ons-row>
</ons-list-item>
```

You should change `[src]="userProfileImg"` to a function that returns the URL for each image in the array item e.g `[src]="getUserProfileImage(request)"`.

And in your component:

```
...
getUserProfileImage(request: TypeOfRequestHere) {
    return 'images/users/' + request.userId + '_users.jpg';
}
...
```

**Update**
Alternatively, this can be done in the template:

```
[src]="'images/users/' + request.userId + '_users.jpg'"
```

Comment: @taku happy to be helpful!

Comment: @taku consider selecting my answer as "Accepted" if it did work for others to see. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, do you think this is a secure way?

Comment: A little confused by this answer. Wasn't the question to retrieve the url from firebase storage? Doesn't this just retrieve a static string / image that would not be served from firebase storage, but instead stored directly in the app?

Answer (score 4):

Save name of the picture, and short path to your database.

Use following code to upload base64 image;

```
uploadImage(name, data) {
    let promise = new Promise((res,rej) => {
        let fileName = name + ".jpg";
        let uploadTask = firebase.storage().ref(`/posts/${fileName}`).put(data);
        uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot) {
        }, function(error) {
            rej(error);
        }, function() {
        var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
            res(downloadURL);
        });
    });
    return promise;
 }
```

it's just 2 lines of code to get actual url securely with permissions.

```
this.storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('images/image.png');
this.storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => console.log(url) );
```

If you need more optons like passing strings, URI's etc, you can checkout [my blog post about uploading, and getting data from firebase storage using angularfire2.](http://muhammetbakan.com/angular2-ionic2-how-to-upload-and-get-image-from-firebase-storage/)

I hope it helps somebody.